# Como fazer downloads pelo Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, object-pascal

Olá, criei uma aplicação no `Delphi`, mas ela precisa fazer download de alguns arquivos que eu tenho em um site, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isto, me ajude por favor. Dez de já agradeço por ter lido minha pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função `URLDownloadToFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx):

```
// Inclua em "Uses" a unit "Urlmon"
function BaixarArquivo(const URL, SalvarComo: string): Boolean;
var
  H: HRESULT;
begin
  H := URLDownloadToFile(nil, pchar(URL),
                              pchar(SalvarComo),
                              0,
                              nil);
  Result := H = S_OK;
end;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
if BaixarArquivo('http://www.fooBAR.com/baz.poo', 'C:\baz.poo') then
  ShowMessage('Arquivo baixado com sucesso!')
else
  ShowMessage('Falha ao baixar arquivo.');
```

Há também como fazer isto com o componente [`TIdHTTP` com o método `Get`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/HTTP_Get_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Por aqui deu certo!